# how to select using where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two dates, **From date** and **To Date**.

Also i have two time fields, **From Time** and **To Time**.

The date field in the database is `Datetime`. I need to select data according to both date and time.

This is my query for selecting data **between 13:00 to 15:00**, but it is not suitable for **20:00 to 08:00**.

```
where Date>= '2/01/2012' AND Date<'2/28/2013' 
     AND CAST(Date AS TIME) BETWEEN '20:00' AND '08:00'
```

Comment: You'll have to come up with two datetime values to do get the logic right.  To do that, you'll probably have to convert your date and time values to strings first and then cast the strings to datetime.  Somebody smarter than me might know how to do it directly.

Comment: Do you only want to return rows where the input-interval is entirely in the row-interval? Or also partially

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your specific error/unexpected results, I think the problem is that **20 is greater than 8**.

You'll have to use two conditions:

```
where Date>= '2/01/2012' AND Date<'2/28/2013' AND (CAST(Date AS TIME) > '20:00' OR CAST(Date AS TIME) < '08:00')
```

EDIT: fixed condition

Comment: `CAST(Date AS TIME) > '20:00' AND CAST(Date AS TIME) < '08:00'` will always be false.

Comment: @TToni Right you are! Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01 20:00:00.000' AND '2012-12-01 08:00:00.000'
```

It is a little bit unclear whether you are attempting to generate the WHERE clause variables dynamically?

Comment: this should have been a comment on the original question dude :)

Comment: @gvee, while this answer may have been more appropriate as a comment, one of the strange rules of StackOverflow is that you can answer questions with a reputation of 1, but you need a reputation of 50 to comment on questions.

Comment: Yeah, that was why I couldn't comment   :(

Comment: @DanBracuk - I had totally forgotten about that. Poggy hope I didn't cause any offence :)

Comment: i might be wrong but you put 00:20 and 00:08 while the OP needs 20:00 and 08:00

Comment: No worries Gvee, you were correct after all.    @Pascamel - you are also correct, I have amended my typo.

Comment: I upvoted this answer to help @Poggy become eligible to submit comments.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I promise not to abuse it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your "date" and "time" parts together.

This code will illustrate how to do this:

```
SELECT the_date
     , the_time
     , DateAdd(hh, DatePart(hh, the_time), the_date) As hour_added
     , DateAdd(mi, DatePart(mi, the_time), the_date) As minute_added
     , DateAdd(mi, DatePart(mi, the_time), DateAdd(hh, DatePart(hh, the_time), the_date)) As both_added
FROM   (
        SELECT Cast('2013-02-28' As datetime) As the_date
             , Cast('08:30' As datetime) As the_time
       ) As example
```

You can then use the resultant values in your comparison